# How to plot this type of matrix in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

i have this matrix

```
     CL r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 
[1,] 25  0  1  0  0  1  0  
[2,] 30  5  3  1  1  1  1  
[3,] 35  1  0  1  0  0  1  
[4,] 40  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I would like plot it in this manner (from excel example)

[image]

and

[image]

I can do it with `ggplot2`? or with other package?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your **2nd plot**:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df_series<-as.data.frame(matrix_series)
colnames(df_series)<-c("CL", "Series1","Series2","Series3","Series4","Series5", "Series6")
df_series.tall<-melt(df_series, id.vars="CL")
ggplot(df_series.tall, aes(x=CL,y=value, color=variable))+geom_smooth()
```

For the **1st plot**:

```
ggplot(df_series.tall, aes(x=variable,y=value, fill=factor(CL)))+geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```